# How can i do chroma keying in flex/actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need to develop a flex component which can take two videos and mix them using chroma keying. Is there library support in adobe flex for chroma keying. How can i get it done . Is there a sample code snippet for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the idea is, you don't play the "blue-box-video". Rather than that, every frame, you copy it's content into a `BitmapData` using `BitmapData::draw`. Then with `BitmapData::threshold` or other methods, you try to cut out the background. The resulting `BitmapData` is put on top of the other video.

You might wanna have a look at PixelBender to get better results.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to do chroma keying in the server side. For example, if we use flash media server, does it have features to do the mixing?

Comment: Well, basically you can do everything on the server side, however FMS is not designed for that to my knowledge. If you need a more elaborate answer, I suppose you should ask a new question.